# Should I hide SASS files from browsing?

Tags: apache, nginx, sass

When developing our sites we commit our SASS files and css files to git and release that code to a DTAP environment. Those SASS (or SCSS) files are readable for everyone when you know the url. This way you can read the sass files from the browser.

Is there a security issue or something about this? Should we disable the browsing of these files?

Ik hope someone is able to help!

Thanks

Comment: IN general one should never publish data not required in public, right? Question is why you _do_ publish those files explicitly. Why not only publish the output of the compilation step?

Comment: Hi @arkascha good question. We publish this for certain projects because the systems we use to do this are not able to exclude these files unfortunately.

Because we have lots of sites on different servers it's a lot of work to disable viewing of these files. We want to disable this, but we need to know if it is a critical change or not. I'm guessing it's not, but it doesn't hurt to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A security problem would only exist if the SASS files contain sensitive information (usernames, passwords, API keys, file paths).  Sometimes developers add sensitive comments to source files, so inform your team of the risk and don't consider it to be a critical priority.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think this provides me with the stuff I needed to know and probably already knew.